# CSS: Advanced row layout with one column having a relative maximum width

Tags: css

I'm looking to achieve the following effect with CSS and without using a fixed number of pixels for specifying a width (I struggle with a verbal description, but here it is):

> A row layout with two "columns", the left column of variable length text and the right column of variable number of icons; such that both columns float left and grow dynamically as text/icons are added, but when the text column expands such that the maximum width is reached, the text within is truncated with ellipsis; whereas the icon column is never truncated.

Easier would be to look at two screenshots and the codepen I link to below. The codepen implements the effect that I'm after, but uses a constant for the width of the icons.

Is there a way to achieve using standard CSS **without the constant**?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/felixilef/pen/RwopwyV

[image: Not truncated]
[image: Truncated]

```css
.page {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
.row {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.icons {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: solid 1px orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: calc(100% - 65px);
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <ul>
  <li class="row">
    <span class="text"> Some text.</span>
    <span class="icons">☆ ☆ ☆</span>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="text"> Some long text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    <span class="icons">☆ ☆ ☆</span>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, so you want the replace the 65px constant value which accounts for the icon container width (when there are only three stars) in `calc(100% - 65px)` with a relative unit?

Comment: @TannerDolby Yes, I want to replace the `calc(100% - 65px)` with another approach that doesn't use a constant like `65px` since I want the number of icons and the width of the icons to vary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a Flexbox?

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  [...]
}

.icons {
   flex: 0 0 auto;
   [...]
}
```

You can remove `display: inline-block;`, the Flex container will take care of that while the definition of `flex: 0 0 auto;` tells the icons-container to neither shrink or grow and to automatically determine its needed size. The text-container should get resized properly by default.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/furiosys/pen/gOLmOVe

Comment: Hey @fuioSys -- Using flexbox is fine for my purposes and your solution works great! Thanks!!! (Note, I believe your codepen does not show your suggestions).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to save it - got it corrected.